# MySQL Insert error with null values

Tags: php, mysql

So i'm trying to insert  data into a MySQL table from an array that contains multiple arrays which hold data for each row of a table using the code below:

```
if (is_array($tbl_data)){
$sql = "INSERT INTO teshsting (agent, event , data1,data2,data3,data4,data5) values ";  
$arrayValues = array();
foreach ($tbl_data as $row){

    $agent = mysql_real_escape_string($row[0]);
    $event = mysql_real_escape_string($row[1]);
    $data1 = mysql_real_escape_string($row[2]);
    $data2 = mysql_real_escape_string($row[3]);
    $data3 = mysql_real_escape_string($row[4]);
    $data4 = mysql_real_escape_string($row[5]);
    $data5 = mysql_real_escape_string($row[6]);

    $value = "($agent,$event,$data1,$data2,$data3,$data4,$data5)";
    array_push($arrayValues, $value);
}   
$sql .=implode(',', $arrayValues);
```

Quick check using `var_dum($sql)` produces the following:

```
INSERT INTO teshsting (agent, event , data1,data2,data3,data4,data5) values (NONE,QUEUESTART,,,,,)/////
```

The above Sql is invalid due to the multiple commas here :`(NONE,QUEUESTART,,,,,)`which are generated by empty fields. How can I insert single quotations inside the query to make it valid ? i.e the correct sql syntax:

```
INSERT INTO teshsting (agent, event , data1,data2,data3,data4,data5) values (NONE,QUEUESTART,'','','','','')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

```
$data1 = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($foo) . "'";
```

or

```
$value = "(...,'$data1',...)";
```

Just don't try both options, which would give you `(...,''$data1'',...)` and kill the query with syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks this sort of fixed it but I ran into another error which i'm not to sure about. Why does `values (Local/120@disc-agents/n,ADDMEMBER,'','','','','')` cause an sql syntax error?

Comment: does `local/120@disc-agents/n` look like a valid field name to you?

Comment: I am inserting the string `local/120@disc-agents/n` it is not a Field Name.

Comment: then put quotes around it too. `insert ... values (Foo)` is telling the db to use whatever value is in the `Foo` field, which makes no sense, because there's no existing record to get that value from in the first place. `insert ... values ('Foo')` is just a string that contains the letters `F`, `o`, `o`.